# Importing a UV Map with Python

Tags: python, uv

I'm writing a python script to create some simple objects in Blender. Outside of the script I've created UV maps (exported as PNGs) from objects with the exact same geometry as the objects . How can I, using Python, import those PNG file UV maps?

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create an image texture for the objects that I create via script. I'm using Cycles.

EDIT: Here's my exported UV File[image: UV Map PNG]

Here's a code snippet of what I'm doing:

```
import bpy

# Use Cycles
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.engine = 'CYCLES'

# Create Sphere
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(size=2, location=(0, 0, 3), segments=64, ring_count=32)
sphere01 = bpy.context.active_object

# Create new material
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Test Material")
mat.use_nodes = True

# Assign Test Material to sphere
sphere01.data.materials.append(mat)

# Create the image texture node
try:
    img = bpy.data.images.load("//somefile.jpg", check_existing=False)
except NameError:
    print("Cannot load image %s" % "somefile.jpg")
img_node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
img_node.image = img

# Link the image texture node
mat.node_tree.links.new(mat.node_tree.nodes.get('Diffuse BSDF').inputs.get("Color"), img_node.outputs.get("Color"))

# ---------------------------------------------------------

# SOMEHOW IMPORT THE FILE UV_MAP.png AS A UV MAP

# ---------------------------------------------------------


# Save
bpy.ops.wm.save_as_mainfile(filepath="./testing.blend")
```

Comment: Could you please add a pic of your png UV map to the post.

Comment: Updated with pic of the PNG map.

Comment: Ian, if I understand well, UV maps saved as png cannot be used as real UV maps. They are just some guide to see how a texture can correspond to a concrete UV map. So (again if I understand well), this approach can not work. Please ask in comments if this is not clear.

Comment: Lemon - thanks... are there any other avenues that you know of for transferring a UV map from one blender file to another via script? I'm pretty indifferent to the exact method, I'd just like to use pre-made UV maps in a script.

Comment: Ian no, I cannot provide a full answer for that (too much time to do it). But UV maps are accessible via obj.data.uv_layers where obj is the target or original object (say this is called uvMap). From that use the polygons of the object (obj.data.polygons) and get for each polygon "polygon.loop_indices" so you can reach uvMap.data[Index].uv which is the uv data which corresponds to x and y value (uvMap.data[index].x or y). Here is an answer using uv maps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76497/dilate-expand-vertex-color-mask/76873#76873. In hope this helps

Comment: Related [1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36905/uv-coordinates-to-xyz-coordinates) [2](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14074/is-there-a-way-to-convert-a-meshs-uvs-into-a-second-mesh-using-a-script)